# Getting Wiring Harness through Radiator Support?

Tags: radiator, power-steering, wiring, frame

I'm currently in the process of doing my best to overhaul an 88 Chevy Silverado Pickup 2500 V8 5.7L. I do not know much about cars, but am learning.

Anyway, long story short, the engine hoist I have (borrowed) does not lift the engine enough to remove it from the truck. I removed the hood, grill, and bumper (among many other things). Now I would like to remove the radiator support as well, in order to make removing the engine more possible.

I drained the coolant and removed the radiator. I seemed to have to have already had a discharged A/C system, so I was also able to move the A/C condenser.

Now I am almost ready to removed the radiator support, but the wiring harness is fed through the radiator support and I cannot seem to figure out how to get it through the driver side hole in the support. I managed to disconnect the ground and clips on the passenger side and feed it through the passenger hole, but am getting stuck on the driver side. The bulb housing from the headlights and parking lights are too big to fit through the hole in the radiator support as far as I can tell, especially with the other wires and hoses. There also does not appear to be a simple way to unplug the bulb housing from the wiring without potentially have to re-wire, which I am not sure I can do.

There is also a small mini radiator looking device next to where the A/C condenser was that is connected to the power steering pump. I am not sure how to get this through the radiator support, and there is no way to disconnect one of the two hoses that are attached to it from either the pump or the item itself.

I believe that the mini radiator looking device and the bulb housing could fit through the hole if the other was not in the way.

Any help is much appreciated. I understand photos will prove helpful, however it is dark now here and I cannot get a good picture.

I am more than happy to provide any other information.

Comment: The power steering cooler lines are either held on by a clip or are threaded. Alternatively you could just cut and replace the power steering cooler lines.